# Determining the behaviour as $n \to \infty$ of a sequence defined by a recurrence relation with a few different initial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This question concerns the real sequence $(a_n)$ defined by:

$$ a_1 = c \;\;\;\;\; (\alpha + \beta)a_{n+1} = {a_n}^2 + \alpha\beta $$

where $ 0 < \alpha < \beta$ and $c > \alpha$

> (a) Prove that if $(a_n)$ converges to a limit $L$ then necessarily $L=\alpha$ or $L=\beta$.
>
> (b) Prove that $a_{n+1} - \gamma$ and $a_n - \gamma$ have the same sign, where $\gamma$ denotes either $\alpha$ or $\beta$.
>
> (c) Prove that if $c < \beta$ then $(a_n)$ converges monotonically to $\alpha$. Discuss the limiting behaviour of $(a_n)$ when $c \geq \beta$.
>
> (d) Prove that if $\alpha < c < \beta$,
>
> $$ | a_n - \alpha| \leq \left( \frac{\alpha + c}{\alpha + \beta} \right)^{(n-1)}(c-\alpha)$$

(a) is easy. Assuming $a_n \to L$ gets you a quadratic which has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. (b) is also easy.

(c) and (d) are giving me trouble.

With (c), I understand that if $c < \beta$, then $\alpha < a_n < \beta$ for all $n$, so the sequence is bounded. If I could somehow prove that the sequence is monotonically decreasing, then it would have to converge to $\alpha$, since it does converge and doesn't converge to $\beta$. But I can't see a way to get this from the definition of the sequence. I assume that I could use something similar to show that the sequence diverges if $c > \beta$, but I don't know what that something is.

I have no idea for (d). I assume it follows from (c) at least partially?

I would appreciate any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_n^2-(\alpha+\beta)a_n+\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \le 0$$
because $\alpha \le a_n \le \beta$ as sign of $(a_n-\gamma)$ is constant

So your sequence is monotonically decreasing

You can use the argument to prove that your sequence is monotonically increasing when $c>\beta$

for d), $$a_{n+1}-\alpha = \frac{a_n^2-\alpha^2}{\alpha+\beta}=\frac{(a_n-\alpha)(a_n+\alpha)}{\alpha+\beta} \le \frac{(a_n-\alpha)(c+\alpha)}{\alpha+\beta}$$
so recursively you have the expected result